# Remote directory scanning

Tags: php

What would be the best way to scan a remote directory's filenames using only PHP?

Comment: Which protocol would be used to see the remote directory? http? ftp? ssh?

Comment: whichever is the easiest to implement in PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use a recurrence function:

```
function getDirectoryTree ( $outerDir, $x ) {
    $dirs = array_diff ( scandir ( $outerDir ), Array ( ".", ".." ) );
    foreach ( $dirs as $d ) {
      if ( is_dir ( $outerDir . "/" . $d ) ) {
        getDirectoryTree ( $outerDir . "/" . $d, $x );
      }
      else {
        if ( ($x) ? ereg ($x . '$', $d) : 1 ) {
          $ftime = @filemtime ( $outerDir . '/' . $d );
          if ( ( $ftime !== FALSE ) && ( $ftime > time ( ) - 60*60*24*5 ) ) {
            echo date ('Y-m-d H:i', $ftime ) . ' ' . $outerDir . '/' . $d . '<BR>';
          }  
        }
      }  
    }

} 

getDirectoryTree ( '../', 'php' );
```

It show (echo) all php files what was changed in last 5 days...

And be easily adjust to your needs

Comment: This function does not include a remote connection.

Comment: just pack this into php script remote.php which will run this function - you can recognize API key in $_GET param if you want to be more secure - place this on server what you want to be scanned and execute it from your remote location by get_file_content or curl...